# Azure Application Gateway Error

Tags: azure

I am trying to setup an application `gateway` with end to end `ssl.` Problem is that I am getting **502 error** with my configuration so I enabled diagnostic logs. In diagnostic logs I am getting this error in json form

```
<Error>
   <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
   <Message>
      The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:xxxxxxxxxxxx Time:2018-01-18T10:01:57.3460336Z
   </Message>
</Error>
```

can someone help me with this

Comment: If you test your service inside VM with private IP, does it work?

Comment: Do you oepn port 443 on your Azure VM?

Comment: dint got your first comment how to test that ?? port 443 is open

Comment: `curl https://127.0.0.1` the result?

Comment: https://127.0.0.1 connection refused but we have port 8443 for our connection doing curl to it gives no error

Comment: Application gateway only supports port 80 or 443. You need configure your service listening on 443. Heath probe is to probe port 443, but your service is listening on 8443.

Comment: Also, you need open port 8443 on Azure NSG.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, custom port also works. But when you configure application gateway, you should use port 8443, not 443.

Comment: only 443 !!! are you sure as for probes I configured them on port 8443 same as my backedhttp one also if it only supports 443 how will it support multi site application listening on different ports

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163458/discussion-between-blindsniper-and-shengbao-shui-msft).